# Valgrind output

Tags: c++, jenkins, valgrind

I have installed Valgrind on a Linux system and make this call:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --log-file=valgrindLog/%p --trace-children=yes --xml=yes --xml-file=resultvalgrindMemLog.xml ./main
```

The out file (resultvalgrindMemLog.xml) is displayed with the [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) plugin.

My expectation is to get the line of the failure and the part of the code.

[image]

But my output looks like:

[image]

Why does the message "Source code not available" in the section *Code* appear?

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not compile your C++ application with debug symbols enabled.

With `gcc`, this would be the `-g` compilation option.

Comment: I have try to build wie -g flag: compile :g++ -Wall -g -Wformat -c Link: g++ -Wall -g -Wformat -o -> but the output is the same as before...